# Simulate click with enzyme

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I want to simulate click on x,y target in element. Enzyme simulate will dispatch react event on target element, but i'm not able to find info on how to modify this event to point at particular location, not element as a whole. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enzyme `simulate` takes a second parameter where you can pass the event object. For example, I have provided a sample test case for Input box

```
   Component.find('input').simulate('change', {
      target: {
        value: 'Text'
      }
    });
```

Have a look at the `enzyme`'s documentation [here](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html)

Comment: @AnatolyStrashkevich, glad to hear that.. :)